# How to draw a Arc with dynamic angle and gradient effect on its tail in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am able to draw a circle/Arc using a **Brezier Path** and any other methods and I'm even able to add a gradient effect, but I could not figure out how to add a gradient effect on the tail of arc? Because the angle is dynamic, the first circle is shown and then it shows like deleting because I'm actually using circle filling and deleting as customized progress bar.

```
// Determine our start and stop angles for the arc (in radians)
   CGFloat startAngle = M_PI * 1.5;
   CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + (M_PI * -2);


UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// Create our arc, with the correct angles

[bezierPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(70, 67)
                      radius:58
                  startAngle:startAngle
                    endAngle:(endAngle - startAngle) * (percent / 100.0) + startAngle
                   clockwise:false];
  //Here percent is int according to which length or we can say angle of arc is decided. After fixed duration of time it changes so arc changes.

// Set the display for the path, and stroke it
bezierPath.lineWidth = 3.5;
[[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
[bezierPath stroke];
```

I want a gradient effect at the tail of this arc, and as the arc moves the gradient should move at tail with the arc.

I want something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653104/designing-circular-progress-bar-in-ios?rq=1) but could not find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code or a screenshot?

Comment: Is this what you are asking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821440/how-can-i-draw-a-gradient-filled-arc-i-e-rainbow?rq=1

Comment: What is the "tail" of an arc?

Comment: Tail of arc means at the end of arc.

Comment: I think Aadhya wants the arc to fade out at the ends instead of having solid endpoints.

Comment: Yes exactly what @Chuck said. I want the arc to fade out. But as the arc is moving continuously with time so I can not decide point where to fade out.

Comment: @Cameron, This is not what I am asking for. I want tail of arc should fade out means eds points of arc should fade out. But as Arc is not static, It is changing continuously then how to implement this?

Comment: The sample I linked to shows an arc - similar to what I think you are asking for - and the color steps in the gradient. Did you try it by setting the alpha to zero for the color at the tail? That should give you the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);

    UIBezierPath *blueHalf = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [blueHalf addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100) radius:90.0 startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
    [blueHalf setLineWidth:4.0];
    [blueHalf stroke];

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);

    UIBezierPath *redHalf = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [redHalf addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0) radius:90.0 startAngle:M_PI_2 endAngle:3.0 * M_PI_2 clockwise:YES];
    [redHalf setLineWidth:4.0];
    [redHalf stroke];
}
```